# How to change background image of UIBarButtonItem create with interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a few UIBarButtonItem with interface builder and try to customize the button to green color. While I couldn't find ways to change background color of the button, I decide to code in this way:
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnDone;

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnGreen.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:0];
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [doneButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveDateEdit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [doneButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50, 30);
    btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:doneButton];
    [doneButton release];
}
```

I create IBOutlet and link to the button from interface builder while I try to override this during it first load. However, it is showing the default button.

Would like to know why is this happening? Or even better someone can suggest me better way changing my UIBarButtonItem to green.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: why don't Change the `UIButton` image **[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];**

Comment: If I setImage it will replace my title or wording in front. So I have to set as background though. XD

Comment: Finally, I resolved this by manually coding all the UIButton and add it to the toolbar view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one point,

You are de-referring the `btnDone` object- as first you assign it using `IBOutlet` and then de-reffer by using `btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init...`].. what you should do is add it programmatically instead of using `IBOutlet`. it will do your work.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks Ravin. Basically I have create the UIBarButtonItem with interface builder. I am looking for easy way to either customize it on interface builder or code, rather than recode the whole interface.

Comment: Hey you need not to add many more things in code just you have to put self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnDone; just after creating it programmatically. Also you need to remove it from xib.